# vala: Gst namespace could not be found

Tags: gstreamer, vala

I have some problems with "vala", when using gstreamer namespace "Gst"
vala cannot recognise it...can somebody help me please?

Error: `Gst namaspace could not be found`

I'm new to vala so I don't know what to do to resolve it

Comment: Please add some code that you are trying to run, is that a tutorial code you are trying to build ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass something like `--pkg gstreamer-1.0` to valac when compiling.

Any packages you want to use you need to tell the compiler about.  There are 34 packages distributed with valac which use the "Gst" namespace, and you don't give any information about what you're actually trying to do…  Most of the basic stuff is in `gstreamer-1.0` (or, if you're using 0.10, `gstreamer-0.10`), but you'll likely end up using at least a couple others.

Comment: I us anjunta and when compiling the code I get this: error: Package `gstreamer-vaapi-0.10' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories

Comment: it is ok now,  something with anjuta goes wrong...I juste get the code of my source file and paste it into another new projet after to that there were no problems.