# The namespace name `GL' could not be found while compiling Vala code with Ninja

Tags: c#, macos, opengl, vala, ninja

context: Mid 2011 iMac, MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6, fish terminal

So, i'm trying to build an application, and i've followed the checklist that the developper gave so far. All dependencies are met because otherwise running Meson wouldn't've worked. Dev says "run `ninja -C build` or `ninja -C build install` to install the application."

i do that and immediately it fails. 12 errors. all related to OpenGL, i think.

```
../Engine/Engine.vala:2.7-2.8: error: The namespace name `GL' could not be found
using GL;
      ^^
../Engine/Rendering/OpenGLRenderer/OpenGLFrameBuffer.vala:1.7-1.8: error: The namespace name `GL' could not be found
using GL;
      ^^
../Engine/Rendering/OpenGLRenderer/OpenGLRenderBuffer.vala:1.7-1.8: error: The namespace name `GL' could not be found
using GL;
      ^^
../Engine/Rendering/OpenGLRenderer/OpenGLRenderer.vala:1.7-1.8: error: The namespace name `GL' could not be found
using GL;
      ^^
../Engine/Rendering/OpenGLRenderer/Shaders/OpenGLShader.vala:1.7-1.8: error: The namespace name `GL' could not be found
using GL;
      ^^
../Engine/Rendering/OpenGLRenderer/Shaders/OpenGLShaderProgram2D.vala:1.7-1.8: error: The namespace name `GL' could not be found
using GL;
      ^^
../Engine/Rendering/OpenGLRenderer/Shaders/OpenGLShaderProgram3D.vala:1.7-1.8: error: The namespace name `GL' could not be found
using GL;
      ^^
../Engine/Rendering/OpenGLRenderer/OpenGLRenderer.vala:260.43-260.48: error: The type name `GLuint' could not be found
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, (GLuint)texture_handle.handle);
                                          ^^^^^^
../Engine/Rendering/OpenGLRenderer/OpenGLRenderer.vala:334.74-334.79: error: The type name `GLvoid' could not be found
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, len * resource.points.length, (GLvoid[])resource.points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
                                                                         ^^^^^^
../Engine/Rendering/OpenGLRenderer/OpenGLRenderer.vala:376.105-376.110: error: The type name `GLvoid' could not be found
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_SRGB_ALPHA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid[])resource.data);
                                                                                                        ^^^^^^
../Engine/Rendering/OpenGLRenderer/OpenGLRenderer.vala:422.99-422.104: error: The type name `GLvoid' could not be found
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid[])label.data);
                                                                                                  ^^^^^^
../Engine/Rendering/OpenGLRenderer/Shaders/OpenGLShaderProgram2D.vala:60.63-60.68: error: The type name `GLvoid' could not be found
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 8 * sizeof(float), (GLvoid[])vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

It fails catastrophically at the second line of code. Here's a snippet from `../Engine/Engine.vala`

```vala
using SDL;
using GL;

namespace Engine
{
    public abstract class Engine : Object
    {
        Engine(bool multithread_rendering, string version_string, bool debug)
        {
            this.multithread_rendering = multithread_rendering;
            this.debug = debug;
            this.version_string = version_string;
        }
```

there's much more than just that, but it probably doesn't matter, because it fails at line 2.

Now, i know nothing of Vala, or how it works, but from my limited knowledge, this *seems* to be an issue with Vala not being able to find what its looking for.

i've been throwing things at the wall and nothing's stuck. Any advice or pointers would be appreciated

Edit (6/7/21)
I've been asked for the contents of the meson.build  that was used to build, so here it is

```
project('OpenRiichi', 'vala', 'c')

# We use subdir instead of subproject so we don't have to recompile everything when we change something in libengine
subdir('Engine')

dataDir = get_option('prefix') / get_option('datadir') / 'OpenRiichi'
add_project_arguments('-DOPENRIICHI_SEARCH_DIR="' + dataDir +  '"', language: 'c')

dependencies = [
    valac.find_library('os', dirs: meson.current_source_dir() + '/vapi', required: false)
] + engine_dependencies

sources = files(
    'source/main.vala',
    'source/Environment.vala',
    'source/Game/GameController.vala',
    'source/Game/Logic/AnimationTimings.vala',
    'source/Game/Logic/ClientAction.vala',
    'source/Game/Logic/ClientMessage.vala',
    'source/Game/Logic/ClientRoundState.vala',
    'source/Game/Logic/GameLog.vala',
    'source/Game/Logic/GamePlayer.vala',
    'source/Game/Logic/GameStartInfo.vala',
    'source/Game/Logic/GameState.vala',
    'source/Game/Logic/IGameConnection.vala',
    'source/Game/Logic/LobbyMessages.vala',
    'source/Game/Logic/RoundLog.vala',
    'source/Game/Logic/RoundState.vala',
    'source/Game/Logic/ServerAction.vala',
    'source/Game/Logic/ServerMessage.vala',
    'source/Game/Logic/Tile.vala',
    'source/Game/Logic/TileRules.vala',
    'source/Game/Logic/TimeStamp.vala',
    'source/Game/Logic/VersionInfo.vala',
    'source/Game/MusicPlayer.vala',
    'source/Game/Options.vala',
    'source/Game/Rendering/GameAnimationTimings.vala',
    'source/Game/Rendering/GameRenderView.vala',
    'source/Game/Rendering/GameScene.vala',
    'source/Game/Rendering/IGameRenderer.vala',
    'source/Game/Rendering/Menu/GameEscapeMenuView.vala',
    'source/Game/Rendering/Menu/GameMenuButton.vala',
    'source/Game/Rendering/Menu/GameMenuView.vala',
    'source/Game/Rendering/Menu/ScoringDoraView.vala',
    'source/Game/Rendering/Menu/ScoringHandView.vala',
    'source/Game/Rendering/Menu/ScoringInnerView.vala',
    'source/Game/Rendering/Menu/ScoringPlayerElement.vala',
    'source/Game/Rendering/Menu/ScoringPointsView.vala',
    'source/Game/Rendering/Menu/ScoringStickView.vala',
    'source/Game/Rendering/Menu/ScoringView.vala',
    'source/Game/Rendering/RenderAction.vala',
    'source/Game/Rendering/RenderCalls.vala',
    'source/Game/Rendering/RenderHand.vala',
    'source/Game/Rendering/RenderPlayer.vala',
    'source/Game/Rendering/RenderPond.vala',
    'source/Game/Rendering/RenderStick.vala',
    'source/Game/Rendering/RenderTable.vala',
    'source/Game/Rendering/RenderTile.vala',
    'source/Game/Rendering/RenderWall.vala',
    'source/Game/ServerSettings.vala',
    'source/GameServer/Bots/Bot.vala',
    'source/GameServer/Bots/BotConnection.vala',
    'source/GameServer/Bots/NullBot.vala',
    'source/GameServer/Bots/SimpleBot.vala',
    'source/GameServer/GameState/ServerRoundState.vala',
    'source/GameServer/GameState/ServerRoundStatePlayer.vala',
    'source/GameServer/GameState/ServerRoundStateValidator.vala',
    'source/GameServer/Server/Server.vala',
    'source/GameServer/Server/ServerController.vala',
    'source/GameServer/Server/ServerGameRound.vala',
    'source/GameServer/Server/ServerMenu.vala',
    'source/GameServer/Server/ServerNetworking.vala',
    'source/GameServer/Server/ServerPlayer.vala',
    'source/MainMenu/AboutMenuView.vala',
    'source/MainMenu/CreateServerView.vala',
    'source/MainMenu/InformationMenuView.vala',
    'source/MainMenu/JoinMenuView.vala',
    'source/MainMenu/Lobby/LobbyConnection.vala',
    'source/MainMenu/Lobby/LobbyConnectionView.vala',
    'source/MainMenu/Lobby/LobbyGameListControl.vala',
    'source/MainMenu/Lobby/LobbyInformationListControl.vala',
    'source/MainMenu/Lobby/LobbyUserListControl.vala',
    'source/MainMenu/Lobby/LobbyView.vala',
    'source/MainMenu/MainMenuBackgroundView.vala',
    'source/MainMenu/MainMenuView.vala',
    'source/MainMenu/MenuSubView.vala',
    'source/MainMenu/MultiplayerMenuView.vala',
    'source/MainMenu/OptionItemControl.vala',
    'source/MainMenu/OptionsMenuView.vala',
    'source/MainMenu/SelectGameLogMenuView.vala',
    'source/MainMenu/ServerMenuView.vala',
    'source/MainMenu/ServerPlayerFieldView.vala',
    'source/MainMenu/ServerSettingsView.vala',
    'source/MainMenu/SingleplayerMenuView.vala',
    'source/MainWindow.vala',
    'source/Tests/HandTests.vala',
) + engine_sources

includes = [include_directories('include'), engine_includes]

executable('OpenRiichi', sources,
    dependencies: dependencies,
    include_directories: includes,
    gui_app: true,
    install: true
)
install_subdir('bin/Data', install_dir: dataDir)
```

Ill look into the related question, and do some more digging on my own, but its less fumbling around in the dark now, so thanks.

Edit 2 6/7/21:

looking through the meson.build I saw this line,

```
if target_machine.system() == 'windows'
    engine_dependencies += cc.find_library('opengl32')
    engine_dependencies += valac.find_library('gl', dirs: engine_vapi_dir)
else
    engine_dependencies += dependency('gl')
endif
```

This *might* be the culprit, because I remember reading somewhere that OpenGl as a dependency on MacOS is not "GL" but "OpenGL" or the latter with some version number stapled onto it. ill walk down this path and see where it leads me.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583571/vala-gst-namespace-could-not-be-found

Comment: Please add the contents of the meson.build file, it looks like there is something wrong with the dependency declaration for the GL library.

Comment: ill add the contents in a reply to the question, sorry for the delay @JensMühlenhoff